# SQL select all rows have the same value

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to show all rows that have the same product no from the product table. I try this code but I got the error

> 918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

```
WITH cte AS(

                            SELECT product_no
                              FROM product
                              GROUP BY product_no
                              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
select * from product v
inner join cte on cte.product_no = v.product_no
where
    ACCOUNTING_GROUP not in ('1000','1200')
```

The result I would like to have:

```
Product_no   produc_Descrip ACCOUNTING_GROUP     acc_group_descr          
123              bike             1001               semi-finish-A
123              bike             1002               semi-finish-B
1234             motor            1005               ........
1234             motor            1006               ........
....            .......           ....               ........
```

Comment: you can't join two tables using columns that don't exist.  you'd need to add the part_no column to your CTE table.

Comment: And qualify the ACCOUNTING_GROUP column. (In the WHERE clause.)

Comment: ACCOUNTING_GROUP belong to table product

Comment: Are you sure the cte doesn't return PART_NO and/or ACCOUNTING_GROUP too?

Comment: you'll want to properly reference the table it's a part of, so v.accounting_group

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about my answer because some information are missing, we don't know the structure of table product but what I can see is that you are joining on "cte.PART_NO" and this field is not defined or selected in your with clause "SELECT product_no".

You might try something like

```
SELECT PART_NO, COUNT(1) FROM product
GROUP BY PART_NO
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
```

But in order to provide a better answer we need the structure of your table with some examples of data inserted and result expected. At the moment you select "*" and expect 2 columns as result which also seem ambiguous.

Currently, your query select all product that aren't in group 1000 or 1200 and that appears 2 times or more in the table product, is that what you are really looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

for what you're trying to accomplish I'd probably change the query a bit,

```
with CTE as (SELECT PRODUCT_NO 
FROM PRODUCT
GROUP BY PRODUCT_NO
HAVING COUNT(*) >1)

SELECT PRODUCT_NO, produc_descrip, ACCOUNTING_GROUP, acc_group_descr
FROM PRODUCT V 
WHERE PRODUCT_NO IN(SELECT PRODUCT_NO FROM CTE)
AND ACCOUNT_GROUP NOT IN('1000','1200');
```

Though honestly, I don't think you need to use a with statement here, you could have simply used a nested query to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: edited to account for the two columns you added to your output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a unique column such as `accounting_group`, I would just use `exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select 1
              from products p2
              where p2.product_no = p.product_no and
                    p2.accounting_group <> p.accounting_group
             )
order by p.product_no;
```

If this is not the case, go for window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, count(*) over (partition by product_no) as cnt
      from product p
     ) p
where cnt >= 2
order by product_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized version, you can try.

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS P
 JOIN (SELECT PRODUCT_NO FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ACCOUNTING_GROUP NOT IN ('1000','1200') GROUP BY PRODUCT_NO HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )TEMP
 ON P.PRODUCT_NO = TEMP.PRODUCT_NO
```